# Cannot change directory with cd in DOS using Win7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, ms-dos, cd

I would like to change my Present Working Directory in DOS (I am running Win7 professionnal). When I perform a `cd D:\`, nothing happens:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>cd D:\
D:\

C:\>
```

If I do the same using PowerShell, it works:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> cd D:\
PS D:\>
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong with DOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the command:

cd d:\

in a command prompt (dos) will result in the current directory for the d: drive being changed to \
It does not change the current drive.

So, if you do:

```
c: \> cd d:\somedir
c: \>
c: \> d:
d: \somedir>
```

Comment: +1 worked. Amazing, this is a huge inconsistency.

Comment: Not really. CD is not a native command in powershell. It is an alias to Set-Location which while similar to CMD's CD is not an exact replica and was never intended to be an exact replica.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature....

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, standard CD on a command prompt does not change the drive. try the /D parameter:

```
cd /d D:\
```

Help on the CD command:

```
help cd
```

Comment: +1 Worked too. Seems I have been fooled by my unix-behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "cd" when switching drive letters.